# Python - Compare the content of two txt-Files and print the results

Tags: python

I have the following problem:

I got two txt-Files with the name of games as content.

```
with open("20200714_delete_file_later.txt", "r") as data:
    content = (json.load(data))

with open("20200714_ms_games_list.txt", "r") as data2:
    content2 = json.load(data2)
```

Its simply a list of the games available in the microsoft game pass for pc. The script create a list with all games every day and dump this in a txt file.

Now I search a solution to compare this lists and print out the "deleted" and the "added" games.

So I simply need the difference between these two lists.

I hope that you understand what I want to do here.

Thank you very much in advance!

Best from germany,
betagurke

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any sample of your data so you can consider the following example (using list comprehension):

```
>>> content=['a','b','c']
>>> content2=['b','c','d']
>>> added=[elem for elem in content2 if not elem in content]
>>> removed=[elem for elem in content if not elem in content2]
```

Output:

```
>>> added
['d']
>>> removed
['a']
```

Comment: The data is just a list of names, like: [
 "A Plague Tale: Innocence - Windows 10",
 "Age of Empires Definitive Edition",
 "Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition",
 "Age of Wonders: Planetfall",
 "Alan Wake",
 "Ape Out",]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, Ill try it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,4]
 
print(set(list1) - set(list2))
// Output: 3
 
print(set(list2) - set(list1))
// Output: 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, Ill try it! :) But I have two answers now - how I decide whats the "better" solution when both works? :D